# Consuming a wcf service over the internet

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

I have a wcf service that uses the WsHttpBinding as a binding.
This service is hosted on a server that has a public IP.
I need to consume this wcf service over the internet, but it is giving me the below error.

here was no endpoint listening at http://IP:9962/MyService that could accept the message.

Any Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
1- I need to add security on the binding that i am using.

```
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
```

2- I need to add custom authentication on the service host.

```
svh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
People365UserNameValidator cs = new People365UserNameValidator();
svh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = cs;
svh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
StoreName.TrustedPeople, X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "Certificate Name");
```

3- i need to add a certificate in the mmc of the computer

Answer (score 0):

It's a non-standard HTTP port, so my first question would be - firewall / routing issues?

Comment: I turned of the firewall on the server and still having the same error

Comment: Can you telnet to your IP on port 9962 from the machine that is trying to make a connection?